# How should .cs File look for this XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have following xml:

```
<systemconfiguration>
   <filelocations>
      <datafile />
      <samplefile />
   </filelocations>
</systemconfiguration>
```

Right now I have following .cs for serialization(deserialization) of this xml:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "systemconfiguration")]
public class SConfiguration : ISerializable
{
   [XmlElement("filelocations")]   
   public FileLocations FilesL
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
}

[XmlType(TypeName = "filelocations")]
public class FileLocations: ISerializable
{
   [XmlElement("datafile")]   
   public string DataFile
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
   [XmlElement("samplefile")]   
   public string SampleFile
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
}
```

Is there better possiblility than making another class 'FileLocations' which just have few string properties?

Comment: 'better' in what way?

Comment: I have created FileLocations class just to put xml node <filelocations> parent node of datafile and samplefile nodes. Is there no possibility I can skip this new class

Comment: for example I can put one List<string> containing strings .. but in such case I can not name string nodes differently

Comment: You *could* make it a `Dictionary<string, string>` representing tagName/Value pairs. But why should you? A separate class with explicitly declared properties is a much better approach.